# Unable to install SimpleOpenNI for processing on Mac OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, kinect, processing, simple-openni

I am unable to either install the SimpleOpenNI 1.96 wrapper for processing 2.0.1 or my code doesn't run. I am trying to run this on Mac osx 10.8.5 & I am getting this error and the code hangs,

send_cmd: Data buffer is 322 bytes long, but got 334 bytes
freenect_fetch_zero_plane_info: send_cmd read 334 bytes (expected 322)
freenect_camera_init(): Failed to fetch zero plane info for device
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).

Any help would be appreciated